# Can Mesos slaves with two different configurations connected to the same Mesos master?

Tags: mesos

I'm using Mesos and I want to have one set of slaves that does not have cpu isolation enabled as a flag and another set that has it enabled. Is it possible to have both of these sets of slaves connecting to the same master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. A caveat is that Mesos will make no distinction when scheduling tasks, so if you want certain tasks to land on slaves where, say, isolation is disabled you will need to use [attributes](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/attributes-resources/).